# Why is this producing corrupted output? (ncurses menu)

Tags: c++, terminal, ncurses

It produces a garbled mess but also does print the correct information.
It also doesn't seem to output all of the files. If I specify a smaller directory with less files all files are included, however when I do my entire Music directory, around 2000 files it only shows a menu with 3 items. I know it successfully scans the files, it seems to be a problem with my ncurses code.

```
void init_song_menu(vector<Song>& songs){
  int nsongs = (int) songs.size();
  printw("%d",nsongs);
  ITEM **items;
  items = (ITEM **)calloc(nsongs,sizeof(ITEM *));
  for(int i = 0; i < nsongs; ++i){
    //printw(choice.c_str());
    string* choice = new string;
    choices.push_back(choice);
  //*choice += songs.at(i).get_path();
   *choice += songs.at(i).get_ID3().title;
    items[i] = new_item(choice->c_str()," ");       
  }
  WINDOW *mw = newwin(30,90,4,4);
  LSTWINDOW* menu_win = (LSTWINDOW*) mw;
  menu_opts_off(menu_win->menu,O_SHOWDESC);
  menu_win->menu = new_menu((ITEM **)items);
  set_menu_win(menu_win->menu,mw);
  set_menu_sub(menu_win->menu,derwin(menu_win,26,88,3,1));
  set_menu_format(menu_win->menu,10,1);
  set_menu_mark(menu_win->menu,"*");
  wlist.push_back(menu_win);
  focused = menu_win;    
}
```

http://pastebin.com/jVQpLb6A

Comment: That's quite a lot of code. Try whittling it down to a smaller code sample, and include it in your question. Questions should be available to all future visitors, and pastebin stuff might not stick around.

Comment: I tried to shrink it a bit keeping the core of the menu code.

Comment: Where did choices come from?  Why isn't it being initialized?

Comment: choices is a vector of pointers to strings made global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of items must be NULL terminated.  That is, you must allocate nsongs+1 and then set the last item to NULL:

```
items[nsongs]=NULL;
```